# How do I run a command only after previous command is unsuccessful in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

We use && operator to run a command after previous one finishes.

```
update-system-configuration && restart-service
```

but how do I run a command only if previous command is unsuccessful ?

For example, if I have to update system configuration and if it fails I need to send a mail to system admin?

Edit: Come on this is not a duplicate question of control operators. This will help users who are searching for specifically this, I understand that answer to control operators will answer this question too, but people searching specifically for how to handle unsuccessful commands won't reach there directly, otherwise I would have got there before asking this question.

Comment: Refer to this links: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470349/execute-command-in-bash-with-parameter-and-return-value - http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command - http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/ Hope these links help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`&&` executes the command which follow only if the command which precedes it succeeds.  `||` does the opposite:

```
update-system-configuration || echo "Update failed" | mail -s "Help Me" admin@host
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by
>   the && and || control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are
>   executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status
>   of the last command executed in the list.

Answer (score 10):

When with "successful" you mean it returns `0`, then simply test for it:

```
if ! <command>; then
    <ran if unsuccessful>
fi
```

The reason this works, is because as a standard, programs should return nonzero if something went wrong, and zero if successful.

Alternatively, you could test for the return variable `$?`:

```
<command>
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    <ran if unsuccessful>
fi
```

`$?` saves the return code from the last command.

Now, `if` is usually a shell built-in command. So, depending what shell you're using, you should check the man page of your shell for that.

Comment: You got the first case wrong, it's `if command; then echo successful; fi`, and `if ! command; then echo unsuccessful; fi`.  The condition for `if` when checking exit codes is reversed.

Comment: 0 is when program exits successfully. Non zero is errors or failures.  adding ! helped, thanks @lcd047 for suggesting.

Comment: @lcd047 Right, I forgot the `!`. Thanks for noticing.