# Run Commands if Previous Successful (or not) in Bash

Tags: bash

Having read the docs and following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208874/364220), I wanted to test it with a simple example:

test_1.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

let x=1/0
echo $x
```

test_2.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

printf "\nThis is 2\n"
```

But both of these implementations of control flow fail: run test_1, if unsuccessful, run test_2

```
# Just errors on line 1 of course
./test_1.sh 
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ./test_2.sh
fi
```

Also fails:

```
./test_1.sh || ./test_2.sh
```

Any tips for controlling flow between multiple scripts?

Comment: The exit status of the first script, which you use with `||` between the scripts, is the exit status of `echo`. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Divide by zero? `let x=1/0`

Comment: I don't actually care about division by zero. I just have a process like `test_1.sh` that could result in success (return code 0), or failure (anything other than 0). I want something like `test_2.sh` to run only in the former case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I just have a process like `test_1.sh` that could result in success (return code 0), or failure (anything other than 0). I want something like `test_2.sh` to run only in the former case.

you want the opposite of the snippets in your question.

```
./test_1.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ./test_2.sh
fi
```

runs `test_2.sh` if `test_1.sh` indicates failure, as does

```
./test_1.sh || ./test_2.sh
```

To run `test_2.sh` if `test_1.sh` indicates success, any of these will work:

```
./test_1.sh
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ./test_2.sh
fi
```

```
if ./test_1.sh; then
    ./test_2.sh
fi
```

```
./test_1.sh && ./test_2.sh
```

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details.

Your current `test_1.sh` always indicates success, in spite of the division by zero. See [Ignore or catch division by zero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28016/86440) for details.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my XY problem, fixing my faulty shell scripting (I don't enjoy sh, but use it when I have to), and sharing these resources!